# Convert an Object (not defined) to an Object with a Type

Tags: c#, oop, object, casting

I have this code:

```
object temp;

if (choice == 1)
{
    temp = new HardCopy();
    Books = p.AddBook(temp, Books);
}
else
{
    //EBook temp = new EBook();
    //Books = p.AddBook(temp, Books);
}
```

This sort of works but on the other side of `p.AddBook` there is an `if` statement that is effectively a duplicate excluding one attribute. (HardCover has Index, whereas EBook has Keyword).

I would like to know if there is a way to create a variable Type that C# accepts (as it doesn't seem to from my testing), and then use that Type to cast the object on the other side of the method.

```
if (book.GetType().Name == "HardCopy") {
    HardCopy temp = new HardCopy();
```

This is what I do to decide between either segments of the `if`.

Something on what I am looking for is:

```
Object temp;

if (choice == 1) {
    temp = new HardCopy();
    (...)
}

Books = p.AddBook(temp, Books);
```

Without having to do it from within the `if`. Then on the other side, something like:

```
Console.Write("Please Enter the Name of the Book: ");
((TypeVariable)temp).Name = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Learn/look into using interfaces...

Comment: Why not create overloads of `AddBook` that take `HardCover` or `EBook`

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I can use Interfaces, but for this, I am using Console, due to the simplisitic nature.

Comment: @juharr Do you have any examples or good places to learn about Overloads

Comment: and what does using a console have to do with implementing an interface?

Comment: [Inheritance in C# and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance)

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Time, mainly.

Comment: A class interface is not the same thing as a user interface; it would be similar to inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OOP basics.

Create a base class for your books:

```
class Book { }
```

Derive from that:

```
class HardCopy : Book { }
class EBook : Book { }
```

Change `AddBook` to accept `Book`:

```
AddBook(Book book, //..
```

Then you can do this:

```
Book temp;

if (choice == 1)
{
    temp = new HardCopy();
}
else 
{
    temp = new EBook();
}

Books = p.AddBook(temp, Books);
```

Comment: Oh, I see, so if I am understanding this correctly, by using the Superclass, I can pass the Derived classes through on Book.

Thanks!

Comment: @Ethirix Yes, but note that when you use the superclass, you will only have access to the properties / methods defined on the superclass.

Comment: I got that, do you know of a similar way to access Derived Class items, or would I have to do that manually after, by getting the item from the Books Array.

Comment: @Ethirix You would have to manually cast back down to the derived classes, but that wouldn't be a great design. Could you not implement an abstract / virtual property / method on `Book`, then override with different behaviour in each derived class?

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstraction for you objects, it seems that a `Book` would be a good start.

`public abstract class Book { }`

Move all commons into the new `Book`. Then you can extend the book with specific attributes in `EBook` and `HardCopy` classes.

```
public class EBook : Book { }
public class HardCopy : Book { }
```

Now you can reference both of these objects using polymorphism like this:
`Book book = new EBook();`

And then you can go ahead and use `Abstract Factory` design pattern, which you would create an instance of either of implementations and assign that instance to base class variable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to create an object with a given type. Reflection could be used here.

Given a Type object, `Activator.CreateInstance()` would create an object in runtime.

For example, you want to create an object `temp` whose type is the same as `book`:

```cs
var temp = Activator.CreateInstance(book.GetType());
```

If you want to create an object based on the parameter `change`, You can save the mapping relationship in advance, and then create objects based on your selection.

```cs
var mappings = new Dictionary<int, Type>
{
    [1] = typeof(HardCopy),
};
var temp = Activator.CreateInstance(mappings[change]);
```